# Installing Django/Python on IIS6

Tags: python, django, iis-6, linker, pyisapie

We are currently installing the latest version of Django and Python on IIS6.  We have followed the instructions on the following site:

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DjangoOnWindowsWithIISAndSQLServer

We are receiving a 403 error when trying to access our Django application via the IIS server.
We have verified the python installation on IIS6 and it is working properly.
We have also verified the Django installation.  Our application runs fine under the built-in Django server, but we are having difficulties getting it to run under IIS.

We presume we could be getting errors from "Linking Django to PyISAPIe" section of the instructions provided on the link above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you create a separate Application Pool to run PyISAPI (i.e. not the DefaultAppPool)?  If so, what user/group does the pool run under?  It's possible that you need to assign that user the proper rights.  For example, see this page:

http://support.asimo.nl/activekb/questions.php?questionid=6

UPDATE: Here's another link with more detailed steps to check that your user permissions are set correctly:

http://forum.dotnetpanel.com/forums/t/602.aspx